# Sending json data via post .ajax() and also receiving a json response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Pls i need help with a registration page which i am coding currently. I have been at this dead end for 2 days. I will really appreciate if anyone can help debug my code.

**PROBLEM**

I am using javascript to validate the form for errors. If there are no errors, the script should submit the form data through post method using .ajax() and also get back a json response.

The response would be an error if the username or email exists already. The script process the form validation but doesn't submit the form or get any response.

Below are my codes:

**Javascript**

```
var errorcheck;
var errorcheck1;
function validateForm() {
    
/*
    error handling codes
*/
    errorcheck1 = errorcheck;
    errorcheck = 0;
    };

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    validateForm();
    if(errorcheck1 < 9){
       //prevent the form form submitting
        e.preventDefault();  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sendbtn").innerHTML = "Registering...";
        var sendInfo = { firstname: firstnameValue, lastname: lastnameValue, email: emailValue, username: usernameValue, userpassword: passwordValue, country: countryValue, state: stateValue, zip: zipcodeValue };
        $.ajax({
        url:"signup-exec.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: sendInfo,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result){  
                    //if the result is 10  
                    if(result.status == 10){
                        window.location.href = '../welcome';
                    }else if(result.status == '11'){
                        document.getElementById('formerrorbox').style.display='block';
                        document.getElementById('formerrorbox').innerHTML='Email is already registered';
                        document.getElementById("sendbtn").innerHTML = "Get Started";
                    }else if(result.status == 12){
                        document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.display='block';
                        document.getElementById("sendbtn").innerHTML = "Get Started";
                    }else{    
                     
                        document.getElementById('formerrorbox').style.display='block';
                        document.getElementById('formerrorbox').innerHTML='Trouble connecting to server.';
                        document.getElementById("sendbtn").innerHTML = "Get Started";
                    }
            }               
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('../config.php');


    $firstname= strtolower($_POST['firstnameValue']);
    $lastname= strtolower($_POST['lastnameValue']);
    $phone= strtolower($_POST['phoneValue']);
    $email= strtolower($_POST['emailValue']);
    $username= strtolower($_POST['usernameValue']);
    $userPassword= $_POST['passwordValue'];
    $country= $_POST['countryValue'];
    $state= $_POST['stateValue'];
    $zipcode= $_POST['zipcodeValue'];

    $check_email=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $count_email=mysqli_num_rows($check_email);
    $check_username=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $count_username=mysqli_num_rows($check_username);
    
    if($count_email !=0 || $count_username != 0){
        $data["status"] = '11';
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data as `JSON` you need to edit your JS code
`NOTE:` You can't use `$_POST` in this case

```
  url: "signup-exec.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
  contentType: "application/json",
```

and parse it in `php` like

```
// Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);
```

OR you can send data as `multipart/form-data` in this case your `JS` code would be

```
// Get form inputs
let formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

 $.ajax({
 url: "signup-exec.php",
 method: "POST",
 data: formData,
 enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
 ....
```

Then you can deal with data in `php` using `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess you're talking about the php code. I don't think the data was sent. Can you explain better pls.
Thanks

Comment: There are 2 ways that you can handle the request, send data as `JSON` so, you can't use `$_POST` in `php` you should use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to parse `JSON` data. Second way that you send data as `multipart/form-data` and deal with data in `php` using  `$_POST`

Comment: Answer has been updated, I hope this could help you @Pheyee